# WebRTC and textTrack (caption) to Peer is possible?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am working on a project where i stream video to a peer. All is ok, but now i need to send the subtitles along with the video. I have been looking for a solution and nothing so far. One possible idea was to create a datachannel but that is not in sync, another one was to use a canvas a re record the video on the fly with the subs and stream that, but is just to much process. If someone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the datachannel route is the best one, combined with insertable streams. They are behind a feature flag now, but I think that is what you want.

Medooze wrote about using them to transfer metadata [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/adding-metadata-to-media-frames-via-insertable-streams-api-for-webrtc-47f7a740e457). You can include the timestamp in the DataChannel message and then tie them together client side when processing.

Comment: Thanks Sean, really interesting!